# Loop for `times` if `times is not None` else loop forever

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, iterator, iteration

Suppose I have a function of the form

```
def foo(times=None):
    iterator = range(times) if times else itertools.count()
    for _ in iterator:
        # do stuff
```

Is there a more Pythonic or elegant way to accomplish this?

Comment: Might be stating the obvious, but you *do* have a `break` condition inside your "do stuff" if you are going to possibly loop forever?

Comment: @idjaw Yes, this is for a decorator that attempts a function `times` times before giving up (if exceptions are raised). If times is `None` the decorator just keeps on trying the function until a `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Comment: That seems fine to me. Personally, I would probably have something other than a keyboard interrupt to "help" break out of that infinite loop. But, to me that looks fine.

Comment: @idjaw It's kind of wasteful, though, because `count` performs all this addition for no reason. Also just generally I hate having to do an entire ternary and variable assignment for such a simple purpose.

Comment: The latest answer posted did something interesting. I forgot about repeat. Interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For one, if you are not using the variable, as it seems to be as you are using `_` as the name, use [`itertools.repeat(None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat), as it more closely resembles what you want to do, and it is very very slightly more efficient.

And if you are already using `itertools.repeat`, use the second `times` argument:

```
def foo(*times):
    for _ in itertools.repeat(None, *times):
        # do stuff
```

If you don't want to mangle the signature, you can do it like this:

```
def foo(times=None):
    for _ in itertools.repeat(*((None, times) if times is not None else (None,))):
        # do stuff
```

Which looks much less elegant, but prevents you from accidentally supplying too many args.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! A way of combining the two cases in a natural iterator. It also gets rid of the useless addition in `count`. Thanks!

Comment: @RenéG Do note that that useless addition is very little CPU time, too little to really care.

Comment: Wait, why did you do `*times` instead of `times`?

Comment: @RenéG Because of the way that `itertools.repeat` is implemented, `itertools.repeat(None, None)` raises an error. Using *times means that it doesn't provide an arg if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Why doesn't this raise `NoneType is not iterable`? The docs don't say anything about the first argument being `None`

Comment: @RenéG It repeats the value over and over. E.g. `itertools.repeat(1)` is like `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...]`